# HRESULT: 0x80131904 error when calling the MS Search Query API

Tags: search, web-services

I am attempting to use the web API to access search results from MS Search Server 2010 Express.  When I execute the query I get the following error and stack trace.

```
Server was unable to process request. ---> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904 ---> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904
```

> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   ----.OnCore.Portal.WebApplication.MS.Search.QueryServiceSoap.Query(QueryRequest
>   request)    at
>   ----.OnCore.Portal.WebApplication.MS.Search.QueryServiceSoapClient.CoreSite.OnCore.Portal.WebApplication.MS.Search.QueryServiceSoap.Query(QueryRequest
>   request) in C:----\OnCore\Source\Portal\Portal.WebApplication\Service
>   References\MS.Search\Reference.cs:line 207    at
>   ----.OnCore.Portal.WebApplication.MS.Search.QueryServiceSoapClient.Query(String
>   queryXml) in
>   C:----\OnCore\Source\Portal\Portal.WebApplication\Service
>   References\MS.Search\Reference.cs:line 213    at
>   ----.OnCore.Portal.WebApplication.Controllers.SearchController.Index(String
>   searchTerms) in
>   C:----\OnCore\Source\Portal\Portal.WebApplication\Controllers\SearchController.cs:line
>   28

The code I'm using to the make the call looks like:

```
    QueryServiceSoapClient queryService = new QueryServiceSoapClient("QueryServiceSoap");
    string query = GetSearchXML(searchTerms);
    try
    {
        string queryResults = queryService.Query(query);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

The query XML looks like:
<QueryPacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Query">
  <Query xmlns="">
    <Context>
      <QueryText language="en-US" type="STRING">OSS</QueryText>
    </Context>
  </Query>
</QueryPacket>
```

When I enter the same search term through the Search Center UI, I get the expected results.  I have verified that the service accounts have access to the database.  Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this problem would be appreciated.